# polygon edge position in maxscript

Tags: polygons, maxscript

I want to get polygon edge positions 3Ds Max with `maxscript`. I have tried the following:

```
tmesh = snapshotAsMesh selection[1]
out_name = ((GetDir #export)+"/testmesh.dat")
out_file = createfile out_name
num_verts = tmesh.numverts
num_faces = tmesh.numfaces

format "% % %\n" num_verts num_faces to:out_file

for v = 1 to num_verts do
(
 vert = getVert tmesh v
 format "%," vert to:out_file
)

format "\n" to:out_file

for f = 1 to num_faces do
(
 face = getFace tmesh f
 format "%," face to:out_file
)

close out_file
delete tmesh
edit out_name
```

Output needs to be something like OBJ file format, but I want to have only edge connections showed in wire frame.

Sample output:

```
[0,0,0],[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[1,1,0]
[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,1]
```

EDIT:
I could find invisible edges via this code.

```
for f = 1 to num_faces do
(
   face = getFace tmesh f   
   edge1 = getEdgeVis tmesh f 1
   edge2 = getEdgeVis tmesh f 2
   edge3 = getEdgeVis tmesh f 3
   format "%,[%,%,%]" face edge1 edge2 edge3 to:out_file
   format "\n" to:out_file
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the vertices for an edge using meshop.GetVertsUsingEdge like this:

```
tmesh = snapshotAsMesh selection[1]

allverts = #()

for v = 1 to num_verts do
(
    vert = getVert tmesh v
    append allverts vert
)
print allverts

format "\n" --to:out_file

edges = tmesh.Edges
for ed in edges do
(
    print ed
    edverts = meshop.GetVertsUsingEdge tmesh ed
    print "ed verts: "
    for v in edverts do (
        print allverts[v]
    )
    print "\n"
)

delete tmesh
```